# Why does nothing changed to open a program in windows while using the assoc command to alter the specific extension to another different?

Tags: cmd

I use the windows 10 pro version and open the command prompt as the administrator to run the windows commands in my laptop. Using the assoc command to change the file extension file to another different (e.g. assoc .jpg=txtfile), I find nothing changed after running it and still that jpeg file opens with the regular program instead of notepad. In addition I can see the only change in by typing just the assoc and running it when a list of extensions belonging to different programs appears. Fo instance I have changed the .jpg file to txt file that it shows only as '.jpg=txtfile" in the list but tyat is still opened in jpeg program not notpad? Is anyone here to help me with clearly. Thanks

Comment: I recommend to look on my batch file code and its explanation on [How to automatically open README, LICENSE files without file extension?](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=7369#p63136) It should be no problem to make the small necessary changes on this batch file for your file association task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ftype` as well. I have a link saved to MS docs that says it is up-to-date till Win8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771394(v=ws.11).
Maybe nothing has changed in Win10, but you get the idea from the above and can Google it for Win10.